# Kendo.Filterable does not contain a definition for 'Operators'

Tags: c#, kendo-grid

Filterable of `Kendo Grid` Has Error `Kendo Grid filterable does not contain a definition for 'Messages'` For Operands .

Tnx

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<IoInfo>().Name("IOInfo").Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.BeginDate).Format("{0:MM ,dd, yyyy}").Width(15).Title(Html.LabelFor(m => ioInfo.BeginDate).ToString());
        columns.Bound(p => p.BeginTime).Width(15).Title(Html.LabelFor(m => ioInfo.BeginTime).ToString());
        columns.Bound(p => p.EndDate).Format("{0:MM ,dd, yyyy}").Width(15).Title(Html.LabelFor(m => ioInfo.EndDate).ToString());
        columns.Bound(p => p.EndTime).Width(15).Title(Html.LabelFor(m => ioInfo.EndTime).ToString());
    })
      .Sortable(x => x.Enabled(true)).Selectable(x => x.Enabled(true))  .Filterable(filterable => filterable
          .Extra(false)[enter image description here][1]
          .Operators()

      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource

          .Ajax()
          .ServerOperation(false)
          .Read(read => read.Action("BindGrid", "Person"))
      )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.Operators(op =>
    {op.ForString(str =>{str.Clear().Contains("Contains");
  })
```